# CALL_FUNCTION_CONFLICT_TYPE

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

I have a ABAP Function Module that calls a Smart Form.

It passes variables to the Smart Form interface parameters.

I suspect while passing parameters one of the parameter - date or amount - is passing in the wrong format.

When I run the program (F8) with the debugger, the Smart Form interface page opens, I fill the values and on hitting F8 the program crashes - Program Terminated.

System does not show any exceptions or any hints to why the program failed.

The Function Module has an Exception, surprisingly it's not raised.

Looks like the error is while passing `ip_amt` variable or `ip_date`.

So how do I pinpoint the issue?

```
  CALL FUNCTION gv_formname
   EXPORTING
*     ARCHIVE_INDEX              =
*     ARCHIVE_INDEX_TAB          =
*     ARCHIVE_PARAMETERS         =
     CONTROL_PARAMETERS         = gv_control_parameters
*     MAIL_APPL_OBJ              =
*     MAIL_RECIPIENT             =
*     MAIL_SENDER                =
     OUTPUT_OPTIONS             = gv_output_options
     USER_SETTINGS              = 'X'
     IP_NAME                    = ip_name
     IP_CDATE                   = ip_cdate
     IP_AMOUNT                  = ip_amt
*   IMPORTING
*     DOCUMENT_OUTPUT_INFO       =
*     JOB_OUTPUT_INFO            =
*     JOB_OUTPUT_OPTIONS         =
   EXCEPTIONS
     FORMATTING_ERROR           = 1
     INTERNAL_ERROR             = 2
     SEND_ERROR                 = 3
     USER_CANCELED              = 4
     OTHERS                     = 5
            .
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
 MESSAGE ID SY-MSGID TYPE SY-MSGTY NUMBER SY-MSGNO
         WITH SY-MSGV1 SY-MSGV2 SY-MSGV3 SY-MSGV4.
  ENDIF.
```

ST22 trace:
[image]

Why is the program causing a dump when Others exception should have handled this error?

Issue is with `p_amt` field.

```
ip_amt TYPE  PC207-BETRG.
```

`p_amt` is a packed decimal field and entering numbers like 1,00 or 1.00 or 1 terminates in an error.

What kind of number format is the system expecting for `p_amt`?

IP_AMOUNT on smartform:
[image]

IP_AMT in program calling FM:
[image]

Result:
[image]

The amount parameter in smartform and program calling smartform having same type: PC207-BETRG. Still the system is causing a type mismatch while FM call. Why?

Comment: Check ST22. Maybe there is a dump in the background.

Comment: ST22 helped. I got an idea of the error

Comment: It's all explained in ST22 as you can see in your screenshot: you pass a variable whose type is different from the expected type of parameter, hence the error.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of Smart Form interface parameter to show the type of `P_AMOUNT`. Note that you pass the variable `ip_amt` of type `pc207-betrg`, whose type is defined in transaction code `se11` as being `CURR 15 2` (15 digits including 2 decimals) in my (old) SAP ECC 6 system, also equivalent to ABAP type P of 8 bytes including 2 decimals. `P_AMOUNT` should be of same type.

Comment: Hmmm... You didn't show us the actual place where the error occurs. It is possible that the position of the runtime error isn't actually the call of the smartform function module but somewhere *within* the function module?

Comment: The error is in p_amt/p_amount type pc207-betrg type. But the trace shows that the system is treating both these declaration differently. One is P Length 8 and other is P Length 7. Why so?

Comment: Also if I convert p_amt/p_amount type pc207-BETRG to p_amt/p_amount type N the call is successful.

Comment: So it worked. Here is the sequence: Program Call > SmartForm > Initialization.  In Initialization there is a call to FM HR_IN_CHG_INR_WRDS. One of the parameters in IP_AMOUNT TYPE PC207-BETRG. I copied it into my Program Call IP_AMT TYPE PC207-BETRG and the call got successful.

Comment: One explanation of this behaviour might be Incomplete Activation of the program. I use Ctrl+F2/Ctrl+F3 to Activate my program. The system tells me Active Program Generated. However, when I use SE80: Object Navigator, open my program I notice the system tells me my program is still un-activated since the program name is in blue text not black. Only when I activate my program from SE80 Activation is successful and the program name is seen in black text. Might be i check activation from SE80: Object Navigator too

Comment: I am asking a new question on this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of runtime error, `CALL_FUNCTION_CONFLICT_TYPE`, is a pretty good hint at what could be the problem.

It means that one of the variables (or literals) you use as parameters in your `CALL FUNCTION` is not the same type as declared for the parameter of  the function module. The type safety of function module parameters can not be checked at activation time, because not even the name of the function module is known at activation time. So the check has to happen at runtime.

In this case, the runtime error says that one of them is a `P LENGTH 8` while the other is a `P LENGTH 7`. No, these are *not* convertible to each other in the context of a function call. Function calls are *very* picky about type safety. So check which type is used for that parameter in the interface of your print form, and make sure that the variable in the program is of the **exact** same type.  The best strategy is usually to copy&paste the type from the interface declaration of the SMARTFORM to the DATA statement in your program. If you don't have control over the `DATA ip_amt` declaration, then a workaround can be to declare a local variable of the same type as the `IP_AMOUNT` import parameter, copy the value of `ip_amt` to that local variable, and use the local variable as the function module parameter (simple copy operations are a lot laxer than function call parameters).

For why the function module doesn't just raise a `sy-subrc` exception code in this case: That's because it's too early for that.  Exceptions can only be risen *during* the execution of the function module (via the `RAISE` keyword). But this error condition here occurs because it's not even possible to call the function module in the first place.